# TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer, tensorflow scan

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
max_seq_len=25
input_mask = Input(max_seq_len,)
input_mask = tf.scan(lambda _, x: tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(x, [[0], [(tf.reduce_sum(x)) - 1]], [0, 0]), input_mask, initializer=tf.zeros(max_seq_len, dtype=tf.int64))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 574, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py", line 816, in scan_v2
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py", line 201, in wrapper
    return target(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py", line 599, in scan
    infer_shape=True) for elem in elems_flat
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py", line 599, in <listcomp>
    infer_shape=True) for elem in elems_flat
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 1082, in __init__
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/anaconda3/envs/tfx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py", line 718, in __init__
    self._tensor_array = [None for _ in range(size)]
TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

tensorflow version: 2.3.1
keras version: 2.6.0

the function of this code is to set the first and the last '1' in input_mask vector to 0.

this code works when the input_mask = np.array([[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,0]]),
tf.scan cannot support tensor with the first dimension is unknown ?

anyone knows how to implement the function or to fix this error? thanks

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] for details on how you can improve the question you have posted. For starters, `how to fix this error ?` ... which error? you haven't posted anything apart from a code block, without any context or values for the variables you are using (`max_seq_len` for example). Also, you should use a code block to post any code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal thanks for your advice, i've post more context.

Comment: @user3598128  In order to expedite the trouble-shooting process, please provide a code snippet to reproduce the issue reported here. Thanks!